# Can you print the graphical representation of a SQL Server View?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the SQL Server Management Studio you can setup diagrams of tables with their relationships. These diagrams can be viewed graphically and there is also a print option.

There are also Views, which in SQL Server Management Studio, are setup graphically similar to the diagrams. The Views however don't have a print option. My question is, is there any way to print the graphically oriented structure of a View in MS SQL Server?

Comment: `exec sp_help 'your-view-name-here'` can give you an idea of what your view is like - but you'll have to take a screenshot or something of that output....

Comment: I'm curious as to why this question has three down votes. Is it just because the user is new, so everyone is assuming this is a stupid question? That is not helpful to our would-be new community member. If the problem is that the question should be asked elsewhere, then leave a comment and explain that please.

Comment: I believe he is asking how to print the view diagram generated by SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. Use the Windows Snipping Tool or use the 'Print Screen' keyboard key to copy a screen snapshot to the clipboard.  Then edit/print the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning SQL and we just covered this topic, I think this is what your looking for, from console, just select all (*) from (name_of_view);

```
SELECT * from prod_view;
```

If you do it from the console (dos prompt (mySQL>) you get a graphical view (rudimentary graphic).  I just did it and it works, but now I'm not exactly sure I'm answering the correct question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this in SQL Server. If you don't mind using Microsoft Access, and if you don't a somewhat hackish solution, then you could create a new SQL Server project (called an Access Data Project in MS Access) by following [these instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-an-access-project-HA010341589.aspx#_Toc257281381), and then opening the query (a view is called a query in Access). The Access Query designer has some visualization features that might be helpful to you.